# pywin32api получение данных

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

Всем привет. Дали задание создать приложение клиент-сервер, чтобы сервак возвращал

- количество клавиш мыши;
- наличие колеса прокрутки
- размер файла подкачки в байтах;
- количество свободных байтов файла подкачки

Не могу найти в докуметации ничего. Нашел такую функцию:

```
def pram():
    phys_mem_full_r = win32api.GlobalMemoryStatusEx()
    s = phys_mem_full_r.pop('MemoryLoad')
    return s
```

Возвращает число 34068992000, это байты или биты?

Также я нашел подобную [документацию](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/modules.html), в ней вообще потерялся.

Господа, с питоном 1 день как знаком, подскажите пожалуйста по задачам, хотя бы на путь истинный наставьте, спасибо заранее.

Comment: Дошло немного, `MemoryLoad` это типа одного из свойств. Тогда думаю по этой функции вопрос отпал) Вопрос по другим. Колесо мыши и клавиши мыши.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос как положено. Излагайте ваши вопросы ёмко и по существу, пожалуйста, и тогда будет толк. И не надо нам заливать "срочно надо", "времени вообще нет".